# How to initialize a DateTime to today, but with a specific time?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

How to *easily* initialize a DateTime to today, but with a specific time?

```
d = DateTime.(??)
#desired resulting time => 09 April 2011 9:46 PM
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Thanks for your answer @Vadim. I should have searched a bit harder.. I was able to do this:

```
DateTime.now.change(:hour => 21, :minute => 46)
```

Comment: In Rails 3, the minute param is named min

Answer (score 3):

`DateTime#change` must be from some external library. It does not work in the standard setting. For cases when you don't have such a library installed, something like:

```
Date.today.to_time+(21*3600+46*60+53)
```

may work.

Comment: nice to know! thanks! (edited my question to remove the Ruby tag.. DateTime is only in Rails I think)

Answer (score 2):

[Time.new](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Time.html#M000345)

```
d = Time.new(2011, 4, 9, 21, 46)
```

or if you just want the current time

```
d = Time.new
```

or

```
d = Time.now
```